# How to handle front-end content in order to display menu items based on the current user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, menu

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to "handle" / "generate" the proper front-end content so to follow a "common" way of managing menu items mostly based on the current user "equality". That is, I would like to display different menu items based on

- the current browsed page;
- the current user that is accessing that page (the page could be related to a user that is not the current user).

*Where* (for example, in controller, view or model files) and *how* (for example, stating checks related to the current user in controller, view or model files) I should "state" / "put" those "conditional statements"?

---

At this time *I* think (mostly for matters relating to the current browsed page) I could handle this matter directly in controllers by using [helper methods](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method)...

Answer (score 0):

I tend to put this into the View files with simple or static cases coded into the View file and more complex cases which would require more than just one line of coding into the helpers.

But in order not to bloat the view file, I suggest to use partials to offload blocks of code from the view file.

One of the reasons why I use the views is that I will do certain user based formatting anyways, e.g. if I list all the orders, then the normal user will see certain columns displayed, whereas if the admin logs in, he will see a couple of additional columns. This is typically done with something like

```
<%if @curreny_user_type == 'admin'%><td> ...... </td><%end%>
```

Thus before I now start splitting up some of the user based logic into the controller and others into the views, I'ld rather have them always at the same place.